# Calling multiple functions in parallel in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code on a controller

```
class SomController extends Controller
{
public function index(){
    $var1           = $this->function1();
    $var2           = $this->function2();
    $var3           = $this->function3();
    $var4           = $this->function4();
    return view('someview', array(self::SOME1 => $var1,self::SOME2 => $var2,self::SOME3 => $var3,self::SOME4 => $var4));
  }
}
```

So I want to call this 4 functions in parallel and wait to all of then to finish in order to render the laravel view, I've tried to use pthreads,pcntl_fork, I even used hhvm with hack, With no good result nor parallel results theres any simplier way to achieve this?

Comment: You've tried the simplest; but why do you need to execute in parallel?

Comment: well, to perform better I guess

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php

Comment: Not entirely sure what your use case is, but if it makes sense you could think about making an event based system, then listen for events from your frontend. (Or perhaps just some simple Ajax calls from your view if u don't need the full on event system.) This could allow multiple instances of your app to work on different things at the same time, but it does come at a cost of adding complexity to your project

Comment: @Jaime i got problems with that, should I extend from Thread and i have my run method but how do i create a thread for every function? in the same class

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that purely in PHP, it's just the nature of synchronized programming language like PHP, Ruby, and Python, to execute code one by one from start of the code to end. If you want to do that, then use an asynchronous language like Node.js or try to search asynchronous PHP library (which isn't recommended because no mature solution for this).

But here: a lot of big companies use synchronous language for their site like Google, Youtube, Bootcamp, etc. Most of the time what you really need is to be clever about the execution of your program first, then if you really need asynchronize request, do it with AJAX on user-end, but it will make your code A LOT complex then what you may really need .